# Problem with SDL2 not running after compiling successfully

Tags: c, mingw, sdl-2

I'm having trouble running an SDL2 program, I compiled the program successfully using this command.

```
gcc -g main.c -o main.exe -IC:\\SDL2\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include -LC:\\SDL2\\i686-w64-mingw32\\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -Wall -Werror
```

Now that I'm trying to run it, I expect to get a window and to log hello in the console but nothing happens and the program exits immediately.
I'm using windows 10 and using the MinGw compiler.

This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

static const int width = 800;
static const int height = 600;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Log("hello");

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello, SDL2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while(running)
    {
        // Process events
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        // Clear screen
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check the return value of SDL's  functions and it will hel you to debug and  see where you got the problem.

Comment: @TZof, the problem is even putting a printf at the beginning of the main function, I am unable to see any output by the program, its like it exits before even reaching main.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady

Comment: @yxor easiest way would be running your program in a debugger (e.g. gdb), breaking on `SDL_main` and checking what happens next.

Comment: Do you run it from the terminal? If so, try running it by double-clicking `.exe` in the explorer.